# How to get size and position of a sceneWindow under mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst

I have been able to obtain the size of a sceneWindow when I resize it using

```
func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, didUpdate previousCoordinateSpace: UICoordinateSpace, interfaceOrientation previousInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, traitCollection previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection) {
        print("movement trapped \(windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)"
}
```

within the sceneDelegate.   But the x,y coordinates are always 0,0 regardless of where I drag the window to.   Looking to be able to dictate where the new sceneWindow is located on the mac's screen relative to the "default" sceneWindow.

Comment: frame != bounds

Comment: Nope.    Tried `sceneWindow.windows[0].frame` and still get 0,0.    Dragging the window does not call the sceneDelegate.   Only a resize triggers the didUpdate call.

Comment: You can access underlying NSWindow using embedded bundle. See https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit.

Comment: Its not really all that clear how to accomplish this from his blog.   I have created a Target that has only a NSBundle and an NSObject class that is that bundle's principle class. It's not clear how to bridge to the underlying NSWIndow.   The author shows examples, but does not provide any examples.

Comment: any examples in code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to convert window frame from windowScene coordinateSpace to UIScreen coordinateSpace

```
windowFrame = [window convertRect:window.frame toCoordinateSpace:window.windowScene.screen.coordinateSpace];
```

Comment: No, this returns the coordinates within the NSUIWiIndow.   Not the global screen 
 coordinates.  In Swift this is `let windowFrame = window!.convert(window!.frame, to: UIScreen.main.coordinateSpace)`

Comment: I used this to construct a screenshot from all windows and works fine with me.

Comment: Do you get back a position other than (0,0) for the returned windowFrame?

Answer (score 0):

#### Well

I didn't find a way to get this done in UIWindow but remember, Catalyst does support AppKit and you can call it anytime use objc runtime.

---

So here comes up the idea:

- Get NSWindows from NSApplication
- Get UIWindow from view.window
- Compare some magic and lookup our target NSWindow
- Get the frame of that NSWindow

```
var targetNSWindow: AnyObject? = nil
let nsWindows = (NSClassFromString("NSApplication")?.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication.windows") as? [AnyObject])!
for nsWindow in nsWindows {
    let uiWindows = nsWindow.value(forKeyPath: "uiWindows") as? [UIWindow] ?? []
    if uiWindows.contains(view.window!) {
        targetNSWindow = nsWindow
    }
}
if let found = targetNSWindow {
    print(found.value(forKeyPath: "_frame")!)
}
```

---

And here is a sample output.

```
NSRect: {{818, 296}, {964, 614}}
```

---

A little bit more, you can have your window information from sceneDelegate and compare the magic with it in a similar way. But be careful, sometimes you don't have any window when the app just loads. Do the jobs in DispatchQueue.main.async block if that happens.